# Obtaining call status after making a call in Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I am making a call using Twilio's PHP API:

```
$client->account->calls->create(
            "+17xxxxxxxx", 
            $to, 
            $url,
            array( 
            'Method' => "GET", 
            'FallbackMethod' => "GET", 
            'StatusCallbackMethod' => "GET", 
            'Record' => "false", 
            ));
```

When I look at Twilio's documentation, I see that I need to access the actionURl. However, I am not sure how to do so using my code. Will anyone know what the PHP code will be to find parameters such as call failed or call duration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Calls instance resource documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance). You can obtain all information about a call if you know what the `CallSid` is. The `create` method will return a `CallSid`, so you can use that to get the duration of the call:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create("+14158675309", "+14155551212", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array());
echo $call->sid;
```

Check out [this example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-1) for a more complete code snippet.

Also, once you know the sid, if you store it in your application later on you can use the Twilio REST API to re-request the resource for that specific Call:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->get("CA42ed11f93dc08b952027ffbc406d0868");
echo $call->duration;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how can i find the CallSid

Comment: when you create the call with `$client->account->calls->create` you get the CallSid back.